# How to get the coordinates of a polygon in OpenLayers3 on draw end

Tags: polygon, openlayers-3

I have tried to add a click handler to the map, but am not sure how to tell when the polygon has finished drawing.
Is there a simple function to get the polygon coordinates on draw end ?

Comment: Are you trying to find the coordinates of the polygon or to find if it is closed?

Comment: just find the coordinates of the polygon I drawed

Comment: Is this in OpenLayers 2 or OpenLayers 3, because you put one in the title and tagged the other?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably adapt https://stackoverflow.com/a/24835176/228885 for your purposes. As mentioned in another answer `feature.once('change', ...)` might be another way to go. I expect in that case you would pick the last element from the feature passed to the handler. Then you would extract the coordinates out of it and off you go.

TLDR; Listen `add` or `change` of features, extract coordinate.